# JS Toggle Menu acts as back to top button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a toggle menu button that uses JS to toggle on/off. Just until recently I've noticed that it acts as a back to top function as well if I toggle on the menu while away from the top of the page, it instantly brings me to the top of the page. Not sure exactly why it is as I am a total JS noob. Would much appreciate if anyone could help out with this.

```
    <!--HTML MARKUP-->
    <header class="menu">
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('drop-menu-content');">
            <div id="drop-menu">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
            <ul id="drop-menu-content">
            </ul> 
    </header>

    <!--Javascript Below-->
    <script>
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
        else
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Your `<a>` tag (or now `<button>`, if you've changed it) needs some sort of text content for screen reader accessibility. One option is to add something like `aria-label="toggle menu"` to the `<a>` (or `<button>`).

Comment: Hey @danielnixon thanks for your comment buddy, yeah i just copy and pasted the barebones markup without the content, however I do have the content on my project and all is working well now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no link involved here so replace the `<a>` with a `<button>` and get rid of the `href="#"`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for that quick reply, such a quick and easy fix also. Much appreciated !! :)

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior for hash urls in `a` tags is to scroll the browser window to the element on the page whos id is specified by the hash. For example, if you had an element with an id of "my-element", click an `a` element with `href="#my-element"` will scroll the browser window to that element. If the has url is just the hash the browser interprets this as the top of the page.

In order to prevent this you can either take @danielnixon's advice and replace the `a` with a button, <strike>you can remove the `href` attribute entirely and then re-style the element to have `pointer: cursor` since non-link `a` tags have the default cursor,</strike> or you can update your click event handler to use a function which looks like the following:

```
function toggleMenu(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    toggle_visibility('drop-menu-content');
}
```

Calling `preventDefault()` prevents the browser from executing its default behavior on the event, which in this case is to scroll the window to the top of the document.

Edit: don't remove the `href` attribute if you are going to use an `a` element. Thanks, @danielnixon

Comment: Don't remove the `href` attr, it wrecks keyboard accessibility.

Comment: Still an awful hack when I think about it. :D Using JavaScript to radically replace the default behavior of `<a href="#">` from "back to top" to "toggle visibility".. Of course it's the usual approach. But since the value of `href` doesn't have any influence when JavaScript is working correctly, you could just as well make it more expressive. For example `<a href="?hidemenu">`. Edit: Sorry, maybe this comment should be under the question instead of your answer.

Comment: True. I think that using a `button` is the best approach for this, i'm not totally sure why `a` elements are so ubiquitously used for click interaction like this. In my answer I just wanted to highlight why the browser does that and how you can get around it.